# Gap Between TDs and Images in Email - Outlook 2007, 2008, 2010, 2013

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I'm working on making an email campaign and currently in Outlook 7, 8, 10 and 13 there is vertical spacing between either the td's or img tags. I've tried putting 0 padding, margin on both the images and td's. I've tried display:block on the images and floating:left. My TD's have line height:0 and font-size:0;

```
<TR>

<TD style="padding:0;margin:0 0 0 0;">

    <TABLE CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" ALIGN="CENTER">

    <TR>

    <TD BGCOLOR="#ff0000" HEIGHT="93" WIDTH="262" style="line-height:0; font-size:0px; padding:0;margin:0 0 0 0;">
    <IMG SRC="" 
    ALT="" BORDER="0" HEIGHT="93" WIDTH="262"  style="display:block;float:left;padding:0;margin:0 0 0 0; height:93px; width:262px;align:absmiddle;">
    </TD>

    <TD BGCOLOR="#00ff00" HEIGHT="93" WIDTH="198" style="line-height:0; font-size:0px; padding:0;margin:0 0 0 0;">
    <A HREF="http://flipittowin.com">
    <IMG SRC="" 
    ALT="" BORDER="0" HEIGHT="93" WIDTH="198" style="display:block;float:left;padding:0;margin:0 0 0 0; height:93px; width:198px;align:absmiddle;">
    </A>
    </TD>

    <TD BGCOLOR="#0000ff" HEIGHT="93" WIDTH="267" style="line-height:0; font-size:0px; padding:0;margin:0 0 0 0;">
    <IMG SRC="" 
    ALT="" BORDER="0" HEIGHT="93" WIDTH="267" style="display:block;float:left;padding:0;margin:0 0 0 0; height:93px; width:267px;align:absmiddle;">
    </TD>

    </TR>

    </TABLE>

</TD>

</TR>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeWtE.jpg is an example of the vertical spacing between the third TD and an image below it (Can't post image due to rep).

The background colors are for testing purposes. I removed alt & src content for display purposes here.

Comment: Have you ensured your image doesn't have any padding itself? The background may be white and not transparent, which would cause you no to see it and think that it's just padding generated from CSS. That's a possibility. You also have a set height, and if it doesn't fill that height up, the next line of code next to that set height would be vertically aligning it, again creating that extra spacing.

Comment: Yes the image doesn't having padding. The image's and TD's all have 0 padding, 0 margin and exact heights. The height of the image is the same as i'm setting here (works in every other email application). I also tried inline CSS style and using the height/width generic attributes.

Comment: Try negative margining on that image just for testing purposes and see if it works. Keep in mind, not experienced with emails in Outlook, just trying to help. If that negative margining works to position it, then you know that your padding:0/margin:0 efforts aren't being ignored, and you can begin to narrow your search for a different problem. If that DOESN'T work, then you may look into padding/margin issues within Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out a solution to this problem. I reduced the px size of the TD to 92 pixels (was 93 previously). The Img tag was given the height of 93px. Therefore, that height given to the Img defines the height and displays my 93px image but gets rid of the 1px space between the image and the TD.

Answer (score 0):

For the `td`s that only have images, close the `td` on the same line that you have the `img`.

E.g.

***DO THIS:***

```
<td>
    <img src="imagesource" alt="imagealt"></td>
```

***DON'T THIS:***

```
<td>
    <img src="imagesource" alt="imagealt">
</td>
```

Comment: Hey Arbel. I gave this a shot and sadly no luck. I made the TD height 1 px shorter (92 instead of 93) than the image (93px). It worked but that was a quick patch up for outlook. But it doesn't seem like a proper solution.

Comment: Thanks Dylan Bodnar, making the TD height 1px shorter than the image also worked for me - along with line-height equal to image height - worked for Outlook 2007.